# Blank Page in magento after login

Tags: magento

I am using magento and my page is blank

Here is screenshot. Does anybody have idea how to do this . While debugging got this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Creativestyle_CheckoutByAmazon_Helper_Data' not found in /home/s9webnno/public_html/angelawatch/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

Comment: Did you created Helper file ?

Comment: i m new to magento ..Can you please tell me how to create.

Comment: Others have answered below, but just FYI:  Class names in Magento are file paths.  Stick ".php" at the end, and replace the underscores with slashes (directory separators) and that's the file it's referencing.  Magento first looks in app/code/local, then app/code/community, then app/code/core to attempt to load the class/file.


A Helper (`Data.php`) is required if you want to use the translation function (`__('Some Text')`) which is probably what is happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look for the folder Creativestyle under the Magento root folder, inside app/code/local or app/code/community
There you have to create the file Data.php inside the folder Creativestyle/CheckoutByAmazon/Helper

In the file Data.php you should put the following code:

```
class Creativestyle_CheckoutByAmazon_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your module's Helper folder, create a file named `Data.php` and paste the following code

```
class Creativestyle_CheckoutByAmazon_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```